# Build error related to Jar file in Flutter

Tags: android, sdk

I am working on flutter and trying to include map_view in my app. But I have a build error as:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':map_view:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr} using transform PlatformAttrTransform
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Harsh Goyal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It seems to be related to some missing file. I dont know what to do and can't find any solutions! 
Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled my Android SDK and everything worked perfectly. An answer was posted on a github issue where I posted this question. Here is the link in case it is required:
https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/129#issuecomment-500956688

Answer (score 0):

`android.jar` file must be broken or missing.

Download and paste `.jar` file from `https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms` according to your api level.

Usually you don't need to restart. If doesn't works, restart and retry